# Redefined error occured when mixed to use dcmtk-3.6.0 and log4cplus-1.1.2

Tags: logging, redefinition, log4cplus, dcmtk

I use **dcmtk-3.6.0** to handle DICOM images, and use the **log4cplus-1.1.2** as the logging library. The g++ compiler complained for the redefined error, because **dcmtk-3.6.0** also used **log4cplus** with previous version as logging library.

```
/usr/local/log4cplus-1.1.2/include/log4cplus/layout.h:72:28: error: redefinition of ‘class log4cplus::Layout’
/usr/include/dcmtk/oflog/layout.h:50:28: error: previous definition of ‘class   log4cplus::Layout’
/usr/local/log4cplus-1.1.2/include/log4cplus/layout.h:103:28: error: redefinition of ‘class log4cplus::SimpleLayout’
/usr/include/dcmtk/oflog/layout.h:80:28: error: previous definition of ‘class log4cplus::SimpleLayout’
/usr/local/log4cplus-1.1.2/include/log4cplus/layout.h:158:28: error: redefinition of ‘class log4cplus::TTCCLayout’
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: I guess you will have to use the one shipped with DCMTK.

Comment: May I replace the namespace `log4cplus` in log4cplus-1.1.2 with a different one, and rebuild it again?

Comment: I guess it is possible. It is however not supported/made easy in any way.

Comment: Yes, it is not a good idea to replacing all namespace `log4cplus` in log4cplus-1.1.2. However, the log4cplus version in dcmtk-3.6.0 is too old.

Comment: Hmm, you might try setting up something like `-Dlog4cplus=mylog4cplus` on compiler command line to get this done without actually touching the source itself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks the DCMTK developer, J. Riesmeier's posted the answer:

> The current DCMTK snapshot should solve this issue because it contains the following commit: http://git.dcmtk.org/web?p=dcmtk.git;a=commit;h=e39d1907dd53ad4a16e9aa9e2d86faa84f96ce2e

See also http://forum.dcmtk.org/viewtopic.php?t=4078